# A guy and his teen girlfriend travel through 27 dimensions, ultimately learn that their reality is artificial with camera and green screen

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Its a PG story about a fantasy adventure, very short, about 3 pages.

I'm looking for a story written online about a decade ago in 2010 involving a male protagonist and his attractive female companion. Its similar to Doctor Who in that it involves creatures who have tentacles,

Its a fantasy story where they get stuck in a strange dimension that's parallel to their home dimension, and they find out they must save 27 dimensions which are interconnected in their world and **27** is an important safe word in their world.

They get transported when they've completed tasks for cosmic beings who control the multiverse and after each task they must utter 27 to find the next task in which they have to complete to save the multiverse

There's a camera that follows them and at the end it turns out their world and multiverse are all fake and a green screen was all there was and that they themselves were never real It was a brilliant story, although with ideas stolen from other stories.

Comment: I made the title intentionally misleading for a joke, its almost entirely correct but there's nothing sexual involved its just a adventure fantasy :)

Comment: Nothing sexual involved at all, ironically :).          It was about 3 pages long but still quite short to read thanks

Comment: 27 was an intentional number in the story, also its a safe word due to it has some sort of anti-monster guiding magic which leads the protagonists away from potential dangers:)

Comment: My downvote was for the intentionally misleading title. I don't know what the other ones were for.

Comment: It's not the answer, but it sounds like Magical Shopping Arcade Abenobashi or Tsubasa: Reservoir Chronicle in terms completing/solving puzzles of alternate worlds. It could also be inspired by series like "Sliders", though, of course. If you recall, was this on a blog? A dedicated fiction site?